# How are feature interactions calculated?

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering

How are feature interactions calculated for a pandas dataframe using python? Are there any packages/libraries to calculate feature interactions?

Comment: are you looking for correlation?

Comment: No, is correlation and feature interactions are same??

Comment: To know the context would be helpful. If you are doing ML then ```feature_importances_``` in Scikit-Learn is the place to go.

Comment: Pardon me if I'm wrong... Feature Interactions and feature importances are both different. **Feature importance** refers to techniques that assign a score to input features based on how useful they are at predicting a target variable. And the interaction between two features is the change in the prediction that occurs by varying the features while considering the individual feature effects.

Comment: Yes, of course. You are entirely right. My bad. Still Scikit-lean, though but this module then ```sklearn-gbmi/```. Can be found here. https://pypi.org/project/sklearn-gbmi/. The package provides a module for computing Friedman and Popescu’s H statistics, in order to look for interactions among features in scikit-learn gradient-boosting models. This is why I asked for context.

Comment: There is actually an open [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22383) to add it to sklearn.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58782862/explain-feature-interaction-vs-feature-correlation) for the difference between correlation vs interaction. You could also do a [two-way ANOVA](https://www.statology.org/two-way-anova-python/) to detect feature interaction.